# Regex create non greedy match

Tags: regex

I have the following Regex :

```
^sosreport-servername-.+\.tar\.\w{2}[0-9]?\b
```

which I need to match only similar file names as:

```
sosreport-servername-20161226061309.tar.xz

sosreport-servername-542046-98734e.tar.bz2

sosreport-servername-20161229005243-d252.tar.xz
```

but its also match files with .md5 extension i.e

```
sosreport-servername-20161226061309.tar.xz.md5
```

I have tried also to add $ to the end of the regex but still it cached the  file with md5 ,can  you please assist ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative lookahead at the end of your expression `(?!\.md5)`
So your modified expression could look like this:

```
^sosreport-servername-.+\.tar\.\w{2}[0-9]?\b(?!\.md5)
```

I tested it in (1) N++ (v7.2.2) and (2) https://regex101.com/ (pcre)